# Nodejs | Chrome Memory Debugging

Tags: node.js, memory-leaks, google-chrome-devtools, hapi.js

### Context:

I have an Node.js application which memory seems to very high, I don't know if that is memory leak or not, because it is reduced after certain period time, but some times on heavy load it keeps on increasing takes much longer to get reduced.

So going through the articles and couple of videos, i figured that i have to heap snapshot and analyse what is causing the memory leak.

### Steps:

1. I have taken 4 snap shots as of now in my local to reproduce the memory leak.

Snapshot 1: 800MB
Snapshot 2: 1400MB
Snapshot 3: 1600MB
Snapshot 4: 2000+MB

2. When i uploaded the heapdump files to chrome dev tools I see there a lot of information but i don't know how to proceed from there.

Please check below screenshot, it says there is constructor [array] which has 687206 as shallow Size & Retained Size is 721414 in the columns, so when expanded that constructor i can see there are 4097716 constructors created ( refer the second screenshot attached below ).

[image: snapshot4-screenshot2]

[image: snapshot4- screenshot1]

### Question

1. What does `internal array []` means ? Why is there 4097716 created ?
2. How can a filter out the constructor which created by my app and showing me that instead of some system/v8 engine constructor ?
3. In the same screenshot one of the constructor uses global variable called `tenantRequire` function, this is custom global function which is being used internally in some places instead of normal Node.js `require`, I see the variable across all the constructor like "Array", "Object". This is that global tenantRequire code for reference. It is just patched require function with trycatch. Is this causing the memory leak somehow ?
4. Refer screenshot 3, `[string]` constructor it has 270303848 as shallow size. When i expanded it shows modules loaded by Node.js. Question why is this taking that much size ? & Why is my lodash modules are repeated in that string constructor ?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing much about your app and the actions that cause the high memory usage, it's hard to tell what could be the issue. Which tool did you use to record the heap snapshot? What is the sequence of operations you did when you recorded the snapshot? Could you add this information to your question?

### A couple of remarks

You tagged the question with `node.js` and showed Chrome DevTools. That's ok. You can totally take a heap snapshot of a Node.js application and analyze it in Chrome DevTools. But since both Node.js and Chrome use the same JS engine (V8) and the same garbage collector (Orinoco), it might be a bit confusing for someone who reads the question. Just to make sure I understand it correctly: the issue is in a Node.js app, not in a  browser app. And you are using Chrome just to analyze the heap snapshot. Right?

Also, you wrote that you took the snapshots to *reproduce* the memory leak. That's not correct. You performed some action which you thought would cause a high memory usage, recorded a heap snapshot, and later loaded the snapshot in Chrome DevTools to *observe* the supposed memory leak.

### Trace first, profile second

Every time you suspect a performance issue, you should first use **tracing** to understand which functions in your applications are problematic (i.e. slow, create a lot of objects that have to be garbage-collected, etc).
Then, when you know which functions to focus on, you can **profile** them.

### Try these visual tools

There are a few tools that can help you with tracing/profiling your app. Have a look a [FlameScope](https://github.com/Netflix/flamescope) (a web app) and [node-clinic](https://github.com/clinicjs/node-clinic) (a suite of tools). There is also [Perfetto](https://github.com/google/perfetto), but I think it's for Chrome apps, not Node.js apps.

I also highly recommend the [V8 blog](https://v8.dev/blog).